# ReactJS - getDOMNode() vs using state

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React search component and need to get the value of the search field (text field).

Is it better practice to use getDOMNode() with a `ref` or to use `setState()` when the value of the field changes?:

```
this.refs.searchInput.getDOMNode().value
```

vs

```
onChanged(e) {
    setState({
        fieldValue = e.target.value;
    });
}
```

Edit:

Also, I've read numerous times that if you can avoid modifying state, then you should.  In this case, we have a method to avoid state by using a `ref`, so should we?

Comment: It would be interesting to see the references that suggest modifying state is not recommended, especially as that's the most common pattern is top-down components modifying state rather than direct manipulation of the DOM. For example, in the React docs, there's a complete example that uses state for a search field: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your creating the search input within a React component then there's no need for using the `ref`, just use the callback parameter as in your second code example.

```
onChanged(e) {
   this.state({fieldValue: e.target.value});
}
```

This convention help with others reading your code and make the correct assumptions about its logic.

As a heads up, if your using `.getDOMNode()` and not getting errors then I would assume your using a slightly old version of react. Going forward `this.refs.searchInput` would be the actual DOM node. See [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/#dom-node-refs)

Also refs are generally used when dealing with other libraries which manipulate dom outside of react. Such as jQuery. A common example is

```
componentDidMount(){
   $(this.refs.myref).SomeJqueryLibrary({});
}
```

Comment: So are you suggesting to update the state in this case? ( I am not and do not want to use jQuery)

Comment: Yes, so your `onChanged(e)` example would be best

Comment: I've read numerous times that if you can avoid modifying the state, then you should.  Why is it that there's a way to not use state here and yet it's better to use it?

Comment: Well you could have a component higher up which holds the state, and your component uses a callback passed in as a prop for the onChanged, then this search component would need a fieldValue prop and a callback prop, but no state as desired.

Answer (score -2):

The ref is better because you're not duplicating state.  In the second example, you have a potential bug if the state and the contents of the field get desynced somehow.